# Filename missing first character after uploading to Server on using input type=file in asp.net 1.1

Tags: asp.net

After uploading a document to the Server , i found the file name missing its first character on saving the document and .
Eg: instead of TEST.docx its EST.docx .

I have made the destination folder on the server writeable for the account used by ASP.NET
too , Still the same.

Please Help.

Comment: How are you uploading? Did you write your own code? It's possible you have an array indexing at 1 or something.

Comment: @Jean I have used Input type=file to browse and upload files.This issue appears only on deploying the Code in the Server.Its working perfectly in Local Machine.So we can be sure that there is no Issue with Indexing or in the methods used for retrieving the file name.